# C# search sub directory and files

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to search a root folder for particular subdirectory named "XYZ","ABC". And need to get the filenames from these two folder by iterating these two folder one by one.

I have used the below code to find subdirectory but not sure how to find filenames from this list.

```
IEnumerable<string> list = Directory.GetDirectories(root).Where(s => s.Equals("XYZ"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
foreach (string subDir in list)
    allFiles.AddRange (Directory.GetFiles (subDir));
```

The result is all files in both directories in one list with full path included.